# Usage of the $installer variable in Magento install/upgrade scripts

Tags: magento

I've read somewhere in the Magento wiki that you should have a good reason *not* to use

```
$this = $installer

// do the rest with $installer
```

I think this is the only time I *blindly* follow the Magento convention.

I know it's not about the naming, but the scope, and the fact the Mage *includes* the upgrade scripts sequentially, but I still don't get it.

Why do you think such convention is imposed/preferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know it's not about the naming, but the scope

Sorry, but this is the naming convention and nothing more. `$installer` is a [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) of the installer class (instance of the `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`). Using variable `$installer` is just another way to make self-documented code.

Comment: I know that as much. I thought there's something else to it. I guess not.